# UCS2 vs UTF. What languages can not be displayed in the UCS2 encoding?

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, utf-16, ucs2

UCS2 easier to use in Visual C++, than UTF encoding. What languages I can not support in UCS2 encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing you're likely to care about or, more to the point, have fonts for. UCS2 gives you the Basic Multilingual Plane; you can find overviews of the assigned planes on the Unicode site

- [0 - Basic Multilingual Plane](http://unicode.org/roadmaps/bmp/)
- [1 - Supplementary Multilingual Plane](http://unicode.org/roadmaps/smp/) (ancient symbols, Klingon, etc.)
- [2 - Supplementary Ideagraphic Plane](http://unicode.org/roadmaps/sip/) (CJK unified ideographs extensions)
- [3 - Tertiary Ideographic Plane](http://unicode.org/roadmaps/tip/) (ancient Chinese characters)
- [14 - Supplementary Special-Purpose Plane](http://unicode.org/roadmaps/ssp/) (tag characters and variations - ?)

Of course if you really have UTF-16 support then you can access all of these anyway but if you're asking if you can ignore those then, in practice, probably yes.

Comment: 1 I would not suggest ignoring non-BMP planes as for example for Japanese these characters are not so rare in names and ignoring non-BMP is generally very bad and never recommended.

Comment: @Artyom OK, thanks - I guess that's characters in the SIP then? Yes, I agree it's best to support everything properly but without font support for the SIP (and again I've never seen any) if you ignore the UTF-16 extension area then you'll just end up with two unknown characters rather than one displayed which doesn't seem like a terrible trade-off for the extra development time.

Comment: UCS-2 is an ancient and embarrassing antemillennial encoding of 1/17th of the Unicode repertoire. Only ever use a UTF encoding: anything else is just broken. UTF-8 is usually better for space requirements, UTF-32 is usually better for direct addressability.  UTF-16 is the worst of both world, because people confuse it for UCS-2.

Answer (score 1):

The Unicode.org website includes an [index of code blocks in code order](http://www.unicode.org/charts/lastresort.html) from which you can see that as of Unicode 6.0, plane 1 includes:

- Linear B Syllabary
- Linear B Ideograms
- Aegean Numbers
- Old Italic
- Gothic
- Ugaritic
- Deseret
- Shavian
- Osmanya
- Cypriot Syllabary
- Byzantine Musical Symbols
- Musical Symbols
- Tai Xuan Jing Symbols
- Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols

and plane 2 includes:

- CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B
- CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement
- Tags
- Variation Selectors Supplement