# Strange AT+NETMODE response: 8,5,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,5

Tags: sms, desktop-application, at-command, ucs2, windev

I'm getting a strange response from AT+NETMODE, which is:

```
+NETMODE: 8,5,0,0,1,1,2,1,0,0,5
```

...Is this normal? What does it mean?

## Context:

I want to send SMS using a [ZTE M190](http://www.3gmodem.com.hk/ZTE/MF190.html) SMS modem controlled by a software I made with Windev23. That modem don't say it complies with my current OS (Windows 10), but I had success sending GSM SMS (with AT+CMGF=1) for a decent number of tests with a program I made on Windev23 and also with other 3rd party software. Now I want to include UCS2 charset in the SMS. I know the **basics** of sending SMS, which seem to vary the encoding for PDU:

```
AT+CMGS=<length><CR>
<Message in PDU><ctrl+z>
```

But I'm still failing hard trying to understand the encoding for UCS2 SMS, so for now I used [AT Command Tester](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/download-at-command-tester/) to make me simple PDU messages and test the modem for PDU. I copied their hexadecimal PDU and pasted in a FooString like:

```
AT+CMGS=FooString
```

...and tried to send that command to the modem with Windev. But I get different errors and I think the bad behavior might be linked to the below diagnosis:

```
AT+CSQ ...returns +CSQ: 31,99 (indicates excellent to no signal)
AT+NETMODE? or AT+NETMODE=? ...returns +NETMODE: 8,5,0,0,1,1,2,1,0,0,5
```

I didn't find that netmode response anywhere and can't change it's response issuing command **AT+NETMODE=FooNumber** like AT+NETMODE=1

More diagnosis:

```
AT ...returns OK
AT+CMGF ...asnwers for 1 or 0 (text or PDU)
AT+CSCA="+550101102010",145 ...returns OK
AT+CSCA? ...returns the input from above correctly
```

Any clue would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

## Extra Information (possibly unnecessary):

List of information I've been trying to understand (for curiosity and proving I tried before posting here):

1-Developershome:
https://www.developershome.com/sms/
https://www.developershome.com/sms/operatingMode.asp

2-Online AT command tester
https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/sms-at-commands/

3-Gsm favorites
https://www.gsmfavorites.com/documents/sms/pdutext/

4-3gpp.org
http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm

5-Some of the other links from Stack Overflow
[GSM Modem Send Message in UCS2 format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945968/gsm-modem-send-message-in-ucs2-format-error)

http://d-chips.blogspot.com/2012/06/coding-of-alpha-fields-in-sim-for-ucs2.html

[Adding Carriage Return <CR> and CTRL-Z to a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055653/adding-carriage-return-cr-and-ctrl-z-to-a-string-in-java)

[E160E USB GSM Modem Continuously Dumps Data Into The Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744513/e160e-usb-gsm-modem-continuously-dumps-data-into-the-serial-port)

[UCS2 vs UTF. What languages can not be displayed in the UCS2 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267318/ucs2-vs-utf-what-languages-can-not-be-displayed-in-the-ucs2-encoding)

[AT+CMGS doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932723/atcmgs-doesnt-work-correctly)

etc